# Spark Listener execute hook on onJobComplete on Executors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have a simple spark job which reads csv data from S3, transforms it, partitions it by  and saves it to local file system.

I have csv file on s3 with below content

sample input: japan, 01-01-2020, weather, provider, device

```
case class WeatherReport(country:String, date:String, event:String, provide:String, device:String )

object SampleSpark extends App{

     val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("processing")
      .setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")
      .setIfMissing("spark.driver.host", "localhost")

     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

     val baseRdd = sc.textFile("s3a://mybucket/sample/*.csv")

     val weatherDataFrame = baseRdd
     .filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
     .map(x => WeatherReport(x))
     .toDF()

     df.write.partitionBy("date")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .save("outputDirectory")
}
```

The file gets saved in "outputDirectory/date=01-01-2020/part-" with more than 1 part files.
I want to merge the part file and remove prefix `date=` name like "outputDirectory/01-01-2020/output.csv" and copy this to S3.

How is it possible to do it??

I thought of using SparkListener like below but i guess it'll only run on Drive but the files would be present on Executors.

```
sparkContext.addListener(new SparkListener {
      override def onJobEnd(jobEnd: SparkListenerJobEnd) {
        renameDirectory()
        mergePartFilesToSingleFiles()
        uploadFileToS3()
      }
})
```

Is there a way to run a post Job Completion hook on Executors and Driver which would sync all the local files on them to S3?

Comment: you can merge files to 1 by using `coalesce(1)`. You can call `renameDirectory()` from driver itself. I don't think you need a listener.

Comment: I have huge files, using coalesce(1) would mean moving all the data to driver which would be a very costly operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can run post execution hooks on executors by registering TaskCompletionListener

```
// call this from the code that is running on executor such as your mapper WeatherReport
val taskContext = TaskContext.get
taskContext.addTaskCompletionListener(customTaskCompletionListener)
```

Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/TaskContext.html#addTaskCompletionListener-scala.Function1-